# How to check whether an integer is a perfect square or not without using sqrt

Tags: c++

Also only use the loop while and if else statement to determine whether an integer is perfect square.

Comment: The question is definitely a dupe, but i'd imagine it's h/w, to be honest i'd use brute force so it's not uber blatant that it's been copied.

Answer (score 0):

A perfect square is an integer multiplied by itself, so the most naive method would be to just loop from 0 to that to-be-checked number and see if the current loop variable multiplied by itself ever matches that to-be-checked number. There are a lot of optimization points but I left that out for you.